# If I have two content types with a relationship between them in Drupal 8, why would I want to put a reference field in both content types?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

If I have two content types with a relationship between them in Drupal 8, in order to represent the relationship, I can put a reference field to the other content type in one of these two content types.

But in this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUx0ZlSGwiM), it shows an example where both content types contains a reference field to each other.

In what situations would I want to put a reference field in both content types?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would. I have been a drupal dev for over 10 years and have never had to do it. Maybe ask the question on the youtube video.

Answer (score 1):

If you are user of the example website in the video, I can think of  these two use cases:

- I am viewing the *Event Detail Page*, then I want to know who is sponsoring the event.
- I am viewing the *User Group Detail Page*, then I want to know what events the group is sponsoring.

Then you would have to discuss the implementation.

In the video, they go for two reference fields, I see it as a shortcut so that you have your *Event Detail Page* and *User Group Detail Page* ready. But then you have a new problem, you will have to keep both fields in sync. Having this type of redundancy wouldn't be considered a good practice in database design.

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with field synchronization, you only need a reference field. Let's say the *Event* will have the reference field, now we would have to come up with a way to *query* the *events* of a *group* for the *User Group Detail Page*. A [Drupal View](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/views-chapter.html) would be the most common way to do this.

I think the instructor in the video doesn't want to introduce *views* at this point of the training, because it is a broad topic, then probably he will go back and revisit the implementation later in the course.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simple explanation to understand this point:**

whenever you need a relation between two content types in both directions without using the views.
Let say we have two content types A & B,
So if you need a reference of a field from A inside the B and also need a reference of any field from B inside the A then we need to define the reference field in both content types.

If you need a one-directional relationship then you will define a reference field only in one content type but for a two-directional( can also call it reverse relationship ) relationship, you will need to define reference fields in both content types.

I hope this simple explanation will help you to understand the concept.